# Beamer: \only command with figure inside itemize environment issue

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

I've been trying to put a figure that should be seen alone in one slide with \only<>. It actually works, but the problem can be seen on the following figure (red rectangle):

[image: problema]

My code for this frame is:

```
\begin{frame}[t]{Chile -- CONAF}
\only<5>{
        \begin{figure}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Estadisticas_Conaf}
        \end{figure}
        }
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Principal entidad encargada en materia de incendios forestales: CONAF.
    \item<2-> Principales funciones de CONAF:
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<3-> Superficie afectada a la fecha.
        \item<4-> Estadisticas relevantes.
        \item<6-> Silvicultura preventiva.
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}  
\end{frame}
```

As you can see, I get text below the figure thet I'm trying to put alone using \only<>. Notice that after \only<>, which is number 5, item<6> should appear continuing `itemize` in the following slide.

I'm just starting with beamer, so I think it might be something very simple, but to be honest I've been searching for a while with no exit at all.

Some considerations:

1. Forget about the citation in the figure above, it's done with
   tikz inside \only<>.
2. I removed all spanish accents so you don't
       have problems while compiling.
3. I could "band-aid" fix the problem by
       setting the width of the figure bigger, but it's not what I'm
       looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the figure alone on one page, I suggest another frame. To continue the itemize I used `againframe`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<-4>[label=Chile]{Chile -- CONAF}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Principal entidad encargada en materia de incendios forestales: CONAF.
        \item<2-> Principales funciones de CONAF:
        \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<3-> Superficie afectada a la fecha.
            \item<4-> Estadisticas relevantes.
            \item<6-> Silvicultura preventiva.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Chile -- CONAF}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\againframe<6->{Chile} % continue with slide 6 of frame "Chile"

\end{document}
```

Frames 4 and 5:

[image: frames 4 and 5]

If you want the figure on the same page you could use `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=Chile]{Chile -- CONAF}
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> Principal entidad encargada en materia de incendios forestales: CONAF.
            \item<2-> Principales funciones de CONAF:
            \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
            \begin{itemize}
                \item<3-> Superficie afectada a la fecha.
                \item<4-> Estadisticas relevantes.
                \item<6-> Silvicultura preventiva.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics<5->[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great! Thank you for your time @dexteritas!